# Initiating a new window drag in same position as last drag ignores the input?

Tags: gnome, mouse, window, wayland, 22.04

When I drag a window by its title bar and let go, and then click and drag again without having moved the curson inbetween the two drags, my second drag (click) is completely ignored, i.e. I don't grab the window.

I find it very frustrating to have my input consistently ignored. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: I can reproduce that on Wayland: there appears to be a "time out". If you leave a little pause it will work again. Test it yourself by switching to Xorg: you probably will not have the issue there.

Comment: @vanadium You're right, it behaves properly in X. As for the timeout, I tried waiting for 20 seconds and it still behaved exactly the same. For me personally, switching to X isn't a good option though, since I think I lose more than I gain.

Comment: OK, thanks for reporting. For me, the timeout is there, but it is only a few 100 ms. 20 s is quite problematic indeed.